# Scikit Learn HMM training with set of observation sequences

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hidden-markov-models

I had a question about how I can use gaussianHMM in the scikit-learn package to train on several different observation sequences all at once.
The example is here: [visualizing the stock market structure](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/_downloads/plot_stock_market.py)

shows EM converging on 1 long observation sequence. But in many scenarios, we want to break up the observations (like training on set of sentences) with each observation sequence having a START and END state. That is, I would like to globally train on multiple observation sequences.
How can one accomplish this when using GuassianHMM? Is there a example to look at?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this work if an observation sequence has multiple features?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In attached example you do

```
model.fit([X])
```

which is training on a **singleton** of observations, if you have multiple ones, for example X1,X2,X3 you can run

```
model.fit([X1,X2,X3])
```

in general for HMM implementation in scikit-learn you give it a **sequence** of observations S

```
model.fit(S)
```

Comment: @lejlotk does this work if an observation has multiple features? (e.g. X1 is a vector in R^3)

Comment: Yes, in fact it **has to be** something with multiple features (in worst case just one), fit accepts: "List of array-like observation sequences, each of which has shape (n_i, n_features), where n_i is the length of the i_th observation."

Comment: @leijot thank you. Maybe you can have a look at my question in cross validated that is uananswered http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169193/multiple-continuous-observations-in-hmm-gaussian-mixture

Comment: @leijot by multiple features I mean different features (e.g. cpu load, memory, temperature). Just want to make it clear.

Comment: Yes,this is exatcly what it is for

Comment: Does the same apply for GMMHMM as well?  I suppose the GMM refers to the sklearn.mixture.GMM, correct?